# Wlan connection error

Tags: c++, windows, wifi

I want to connect to the wireless access point. The problem is `WlanConnect` returns 87 error code which means the wrong parameter.

**Code:**

```
WLAN_REASON_CODE wlanReasonCode;
DWORD dwResult = 0;
DWORD dwPrevNotif = 0;
QString apName = "some SSID";
WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS connectionParameters;
memset(&connectionParameters, 0, sizeof(WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS));
connectionParameters.wlanConnectionMode = wlan_connection_mode_profile;
connectionParameters.strProfile = apName.toStdWString().c_str();
connectionParameters.dwFlags = 0;
connectionParameters.pDot11Ssid = NULL;
connectionParameters.pDesiredBssidList = 0;
connectionParameters.dot11BssType = dot11_BSS_type_any;
dwResult = WlanConnect(hClient, &pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid, &connectionParameters, NULL);

if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    qDebug() << "Connected";
} else {
    emit apNotConnected(dwResult);
}
```

I think the problem somewhere in `WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS` structure. Any ideas or example with proper wlan connection?

**OS:** Windows 10

I use Qt 5.9.2 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 compiler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are lacking *a lot* of basic info in this question. 1) What OS? 2) What compiler? 3) What C++ standard version? 4) Where's the [mcve] that we can compile and test ourselves? 5) What have you researched to figure out the problem? 6) what have you *already tried* to resolve the problem?

Comment: @JesperJuhl

I have added the information.

Comment: @JesperJuhl

I need the simple example with wlan connect. Where to find it? Thanks.

Comment: You misunderstand. The [mcve] is supposed to be one that *you* provide. So that *we* can build it to reproduce *your* problem. Rather than just posting a code snippet, you should post a *complete* compilable (but minimal; no more than actually needed) program that reproduces the problem. See also [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) .

Comment: @JesperJuhl

I can't post all wlan code. You can connect my code with examples of Microsoft wlan code [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749(v=vs.85).aspx) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok, you are *obviously* not getting the point I'm trying to make, nor actually *reading and understanding* the stuff I link to in my previous comments.   I'm done; have fun debugging your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. The issue was that `Qt` does not properly cast data types, so the `wlan` profile was corrupted. I fixed it by combining `Win API` with standard `C++` data types.